# RecyclerView lag on first scroll: Is onCreateViewHolder supposed to be called for every item?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

onCreateViewHolder is called every time an item in my list is first displayed and that causes lag the first time the user scrolls.

Is that how it should be? I thought onCreateViewHolder would be called only once per viewType.

Here is my adapter:

```
public class CompetitionTableAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private final CompetitionAdapterOnItemClickHandler mClickHandler;
    private List<CompetitionTableItem> mTable;

    int calls = 0; //Used to see how many times onCreateViewHolder is called

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        calls++;
        if(viewType == CompetitionTableItem.TYPE_HEADER){
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.table_header, viewGroup, false);
            Log.i("CompetitionTableAdapter", "onCreateViewHolder "+calls);
            return new CompetitionAdapterHeaderViewHolder(view);
        }else{
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.table_item, viewGroup, false);
            view.setFocusable(true);
            Log.i("CompetitionTableAdapter", "onCreateViewHolder "+calls);
            return new CompetitionAdapterViewHolder(view);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        int type = getItemViewType(position);
        if (type == CompetitionTableItem.TYPE_HEADER) {
            HeaderItem header = (HeaderItem) mTable.get(position);
            CompetitionAdapterHeaderViewHolder holder = (CompetitionAdapterHeaderViewHolder) viewHolder;
            holder.headerTextView.setText(header.getTitle());
        } else {
            CompetitionAdapterViewHolder holder = (CompetitionAdapterViewHolder) viewHolder;
            TeamItem currentTeamTableEntity = (TeamItem)mTable.get(position);
            TableEntryEntity tableEntry = currentTeamTableEntity.getTableEntryEntity();
            holder.teamNameTextView.setText(tableEntry.getTeam().getName());
            holder.pointsTextView.setText(String.valueOf(tableEntry.getPoints()));
            holder.positionTextView.setText(String.valueOf(tableEntry.getPosition()));
            holder.playedTextView.setText(String.valueOf(tableEntry.getPlayedGames()));
            holder.lostTextView.setText(String.valueOf(tableEntry.getLost()));
            holder.drawnTextView.setText(String.valueOf(tableEntry.getDraw()));
            holder.wonTextView.setText(String.valueOf(tableEntry.getWon()));
            String crestUrl = NetworkUtils.getCrestUrl(tableEntry.getTeam().getId(),NetworkUtils.IMAGE_QUALITY_SD);
            Picasso.get().load(crestUrl).placeholder(R.drawable.default_crest).error(R.drawable.default_crest).into(holder.crestView);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        int type = getItemViewType(position);
        if (type == CompetitionTableItem.TYPE_HEADER) {
            return NO_ID;
        }else{
            return ((TeamItem)mTable.get(position)).getTableEntryEntity().getTeam().getId();
        }
    }

    public void swapTable(final List<CompetitionTableItem> table) {
        mTable = table;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return mTable.get(position).getType();
    }

    public interface CompetitionAdapterOnItemClickHandler {
        void onItemClick(TableEntryEntity competition);
    }

    class CompetitionAdapterViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        final ImageView crestView;
        final TextView teamNameTextView;
        final TextView positionTextView;
        final TextView pointsTextView;
        final TextView playedTextView;
        final TextView wonTextView;
        final TextView drawnTextView;
        final TextView lostTextView;

        CompetitionAdapterViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            crestView = view.findViewById(R.id.team_crest);
            teamNameTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.team_name);
            pointsTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.team_points);
            positionTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.team_position);
            playedTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.matches_played);
            wonTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.matches_won);
            drawnTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.matches_drawn);
            lostTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.matches_lost);
            view.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int adapterPosition = getAdapterPosition();
            TableEntryEntity tableEntryEntity = ((TeamItem)mTable.get(adapterPosition)).getTableEntryEntity();
            mClickHandler.onItemClick(tableEntryEntity);
        }
    }

    class CompetitionAdapterHeaderViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        final TextView headerTextView;

        CompetitionAdapterHeaderViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            headerTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.headerText);
        }

    }
}
```

https://github.com/s6joui/football-data-android-java/blob/master/app/src/main/java/tech/joeyck/livefootball/ui/competition_detail/standings/adapter/CompetitionTableAdapter.java

And fragment where RecyclerView is: https://github.com/s6joui/football-data-android-java/blob/master/app/src/main/java/tech/joeyck/livefootball/ui/BaseListFragment.java

Full source code: https://github.com/s6joui/football-data-android-java

I'm using androidx recyclerview version 1.1.0-alpha01